# Is there a way to find the size of the area in a bitmap which has been filled using the bitmapdata.floodfill method?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, bitmapdata

Basically, I am using the floodfill method to colour-in sections of a bitmap image. That part is easy enough but the issue comes in with the way I am adding an effect to the colour fill routine.

To add the effect, first a copy of the bitmap data is created and floodfill is used on that instead of the original bitmap. Then the bitmapdata.compare method is used to set the alpha value of everything apart from the filled-in section to 0 and the result is saved in another bitmapdata. After that, a 1 px radius circle sprite is added to the stage and is being tweened to the image dimensions and its mask is set to the sprite which contains the result of the compare operation.

This works perfectly except for the fact that the fill sprite has to be tweened to the complete image dimensions irrespective of how small the area is being coloured-in since I am not able to find a way to get the dimensions of the fill area. I am doing an bitmap image update at the end of the tween and I have to disable user interaction till the tween is complete to avoid the errors which come in if another fill-in operation is started before the base image has been updated. If I could somehow get the dimensions of the fill area then the time during which I have to disable the user interaction will go down considerably.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [getColorBoundsRect](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#getColorBoundsRect%28%29)? I don't know if your fill color will be present in other parts of your bitmap, but it might do the trick.

Comment: Perfect! That did the trick. It troubled me a bit initially because I kept trying it with RGB color values when it needed the mask and color values in ARGB format. Once that was fixed, it worked like a charm. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think [getColorBoundsRect](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#getColorBoundsRect%28%29) is exactly what you need. You choose a colour and get the bounding box of that colour in the bitmap.

Comment: Yes that worked. Thanks to your and frankhermes's comment, I was saved from trying out weird hackjobs just to get this thing to work. :)

Answer (score 0):

Write your own fill routine.  As you fill in the pixels, store the dimension info you need.  Simplest would be to just store the bounding box.  You fill by finding neighboring pixels of the appropriate color, and any time such a move takes you out of working bounding box, adjust.

More complex could store a bitmap.  Any way you choose, the point is that you will get what you need more readily by not working around what wasn't designed for.

Comment: I got it to work with getColorBoundsRect but I am interested in what you were suggesting. The problem is that your method requires me to know the bounding box beforehand when that is what I needed to know in the first place. Also, the inbuilt bitmapdata manipulation methods are a lot faster than any custom method I may come up with so I am not sure that even if I can come up with something which works, it will pass the performance test.

Comment: The big problem with that approach is of course that you are now scanning pixels twice.  The point of my comment was that the API doesn't provide both capabilities in the same algorithm, so any approach that doesn't use your own routine will have to use two pixel-scanning APIs, pessimising performance by a factor of 2.  If this is acceptable, then it is certainly good to use existing code instead of debugging and optimising your own.

Comment: @localhost: On the bounding box, you don't need that up front.  You start with a bounding box of one pixel size around the pixel you start with.  As you grow the fill region, you grow the bounding box.  As to whether or not you can outperform the native routines, it all depends on your constraints.  There are numerous ways to optimise.  Inside AS3, you would start with GetPixels for each growing region (add rects as needed).  If array access is slow, abcsx may be used for hand optimisation.  PixelBender shaders offer even faster traversal.  Alchemy can be tested for even better performance.

Comment: Hm.. you do have a point about scanning the pixels twice with that method but since the inbuilt bitmapdata manipulations are insanely fast, that doesn't really affect the performance, at least in comparison to a method I may write in AS3 ( although it would have been nice if the floodfill returned a bound rectangle for the filled area). That's how it seems to me anyway but I will give it a shot and see how it turns out in an actual test. I have been meaning to try Alchemy for a while and this may just be what I needed to get off my ass and tinker with it.